# Wordpress Shortcode syntax

Tags: wordpress, syntax, countdown, shortcode

I am using the Avada theme on my WordPress which makes use of Countdown Boxes, constructing pages using the provided Fusion Page Builder. The countdown box will show the number of days to a certain date which is output through a plugin called [Days-Until](https://wordpress.org/plugins/days-until/). Syntax for implementing this: [days_until date="15 April 2015"].

I am trying to use this Days-until shortcode and pass the value to the countdown box shortcode using the Fusion (WYSIWYG Editor):

```
[counters_box columns="4" color="" title_size="" icon_size="" body_color=""
body_size="" border_color="" class="" id=""][counter_box value="[days_until
date="4 April 2015"]" unit="" unit_pos="suffix" icon="" direction="up"]"
unit="" unit_pos="suffix" icon="" direction="up"]Text[/counter_box]
```

Unfortunately the code doesn't work, and the following is displayed.

0 (in the counter box)

```
unit=”” unit_pos=”suffix” icon=”” direction=”up”]” unit=”” unit_pos=”suffix”     icon=”” direction=”up”]Text
```

Is it even possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to nest one shortcode inside another (i.e. your `days_until` shortcode inside the counter_box) without some programming.

It's a commercial theme so we're unable to see the original PHP code.

What'd you need to do is edit the code for `counter_box` so it calls [do_shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) on the `value` parameter.

`do_shortcode` is a function that expands any shortcodes in the supplied text (in the same way they are if they've been pasted into the content field of a Page or Post), so the days_until code will be converted to a number that the counter can use.

I would suggest getting in touch with the theme developer.

Further reading: [WordPress Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)